# What is the difference between antiferromagnetism and spin density wave?

Tags: waves, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin

It seems that antiferromagnetism can be treated as a special case of spin density wave with wavelength equals to twice of the unit cell. Is that so?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a conventional antiferromagnet (i.e. a Néel state, where nearest neighbor spins point in opposite directions) can be considered a commensurate spin density wave. Generally, the spin density wave can be characterized by a ferromagnetic order parameter $M$ and an ordering vector $\vec{Q}$. If, in say a two-dimensional square lattice, $\vec{Q}=(\pi, \pi)$ then the order parameter reduces to the usual staggered magnetization of the antiferromagnet. See e.g. Fradkin's book "Field Theories of Condensed Matter Physics".

If the ordering vector is not a reciprocal lattice vector you get incommensurate spin density waves. Often such ordering is also referred to as antiferromagnetism, however. The most famous example is probably [chromium](http://wise.fau.edu/~qiu/55.pdf), which has an alternating moment between planes, and a varying moment in-plane. There are some good illustrations of its magnetic orders [here](http://cins.ca/people/fritzsche/Research_interests_Antiferromagnetism_in_Cr_films.htm).